# Dynamic openrowset in T-Sql Function or viable alternative?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this. Here is the problem:

I have 1-n items that I need to join to a different system (AS400) to get some data.

The `openrowset` takes forever if I specify the `where` criteria outside of the `openrowset`, e.g.:

```
select * from openrowset('my connection string', 'select code, myfield from myTable') 
where code = @code
```

My idea was to create a function that takes in the item number and uses dynamic sql to inject it into the `openrowset` string, a la:

```
declare @cmd varchar(1000)
set @cmd = 'select * from openrowset('my connection string',
        ''select code, myfield from myTable where code = ' + @code + ''')'
```

Apparently I can't use the `insert.. exec..` strategy inside of a function. Is there any better way to achieve this? I was going to use this in joins where I needed the external data using `cross apply`.

I'm not married to `tvf` and `cross apply`, but I do need a method of getting this data quickly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be to change your function to a stored procedure that inserts into a pre-existing table using dynamic SQL (as your were starting to do).  Then you queries could join against the retrieved contants of that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use OPENQUERY and filter directly on the supplied query on the remote server. This way you get sure that the filtering is made on the other server. On the contrqary you could get all the data from the remote server and filter them locally, what explains why it's so slow to execute. So, your second approach, but using OPENQUERY is the ideal solution.

You need to create a linked server to to this.

You have to take into account that the query syntax is that of the remote server, and not T-SQL.

[OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx)

Comment: I created a linked server to test, but the syntax does not allow me to modify the string for the query...how would I pass the code parameter in?